# Unable to run bash script with ant exec task

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ant

I am trying to execute a bash script from ant exec task.

```
<target name="test" unless="${is.windows}">
        <chmod file="./abc.sh" perm="a+x"/>
        <exec dir="./" spawn="false" executable="bash" newenvironment="false">
            <arg line="abc.sh ${some-argument}" />
        </exec>
</target>
```

The bash script has shebang #!/bin/bash.

When I run the target, it gives me following output on our Jenkins machines where production code is built. It works fine on my local CentOS machines. Most of the lines are empty. On line 19, it has { (opening curly brace) -

```
[exec] abc.sh: line 2: 
     [exec] : command not foundabc.sh: line 7: 
     [exec] : command not foundabc.sh: line 8: 
     [exec] : command not foundabc.sh: line 12: 
     [exec] : command not foundabc.sh: line 14: 
     [exec] : command not foundabc.sh: line 17: 
     [exec] : command not foundabc.sh: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `{
     [exec] 'abc.sh: line 19: `{
     [exec] '
     [exec] Result: 2
```

Comment: Ant seems to be telling you that your shell script contains syntax errors.  Possibly several.  We can't advise you about what may be wrong with your script without seeing it.

Comment: Note, too, that if you're going to explicitly exec `bash` to run your script, then you do not need a shebang line, and you do not need its file mode to permit (direct) execution.

Comment: The bash script does not seem to have any syntax errors atleast not any obvious one. Forgot to mention that, the script runs on one of the centOS machines. About the shebang, just want to confirm, that it doesn't hurt if it is present, right, even if I am running bash explicitly?

Comment: The shebang is harmless when the script is sourced by bash.  I'm just pointing out that one way or the other, you are going to needless trouble.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the confirmation. Also, it turns out that dos line endings was the problem. Setting svn eol property to native fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that dos line endings was the problem. Setting svn eol property to native fixed the issue. As on our Jenkins server, the code is checked out for every build, the bash scripts being edited on Windows created line endings incompatible with centOS.